# Trying to install docx module using conda install to scrape through the word doc

Tags: python

I'm trying to install docx module using conda install to **scrape** the word doc and pull out certain sections from the doc. But I face some errors while installing the module.

```
(base)/users/sai condabin % conda install docx
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - docx

Current channels:

  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-64
  - https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch

To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're
looking for, navigate to

    https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page.


(base) /users/sai condabin %
```

Am I missing anything here? Or is there a better module to **scrape** through the word doc?? Kindly let me know.

Comment: On their installation page they say to install `docs` using this command `conda install -c conda-forge python-docx`, did you try it? https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-docx

Comment: posted it as an answer

Comment: FYI it's __scrape__ (and __scraping__, __scraped__, __scraper__) not scrap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On their installation page they say to install docs using this command:
`conda install -c conda-forge python-docx`

source: https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/python-docx